# Can I publish same Unity project with multiple Google developer accounts?

Tags: unity-game-engine, google-play, google-play-services, android-keystore

I'm integrating Google Play Services and In App Purchases to a project that me and my brother have been working on. I've a personal Google Developer account that I paid for but has random email, etc.

I've created a keystore file for the project and I was just about to publish the Beta version of the project to Google Play to start testing IAP and Cloud storage. If I publish the project now with my personal Google Developer account, using the keystore file I created, will I later on be able to publish the same project to the Play Store but this time using our company's Developer account?

Answer (score 0):

You cannot, unless you change the package name.

As far as I know, you can use the same key to sign both, but you must change the package name.